# Use of ionic modal gives blank black screen

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am making an app in Ionic Framework.

When I click on button which is supposedly to open ionicModal, shows a blank black screen.

html code:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>Add Proof</h4>
<button style="width:100px;height:10px" class="button button-dark" ng-click="modal.show()">Add</button>
</div>
<script id="templates/newItem.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Add Proof</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>

    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">

    <div class="list">
        <label> 
            <h4>Select from Pictures</h4> 
            <button class="button button-small button-dark">Browse</button>  
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
        <input type = "text" placeholder="Description">
        </label>

      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

controller code:

```
.controller('ProCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicModal', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal) {
           $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/newItem.html', {
            scope: $scope
          }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
          });  
}]);
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Your code seems fine here in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mjunaidsalaat/pen/grjgvy) i've created. Its something else. Is there an error in the console?

Comment: no error in the console

Answer (score 3):

if your index.html file contain

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

remove it.

Comment: this happens because of .model class in bootstrap.css set eliment on display:none so you can simply modify bootstrap (just remove models). http://getbootstrap.com/customize/